# Creating separate volume for /var/log/ and /var/log/audit/

Tags: filesystems, partition, lvm

I need to migrate `/var/log/` and `/var/log/audit` to separate volumes.   Currently the entire `/var/` directory is on a logical volume with ample space (45G).  I understand how to shrink and create new logical volumes (and the associated risks of resizing and need for full backups beforehand).

My question may be a simple one.  How am I able to have /var/log/ on volume "B" if I've already mounted /var/ to volume "A"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to migrate /var/log/ and /var/log/audit to separate partitions. Currently the entire /var/ directory is on a logical volume with ample space (45G).

LVM is the partition type, so you meant migrate to new logical volumes, right?

> I understand how to shrink and create new logical volumes (and the associated risks of resizing and need for full backups beforehand).

Won't touch that, then.

> My question may be a simple one. How am I able to have /var/log/ on partition "B" if I've already mounted /var/ to partition "A"?

Again, you meant volume, not partition, right?

Stop system logging and auditing and anything else writing to `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit` directories. Create a TAR archive of the directories, `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit`.

This sounds like a DoD system to which you are applying a [STIG](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx). If so, keep your SELinux attibutes and any other ACLs and extended attributes with something like this: `tar --selinux --acls --xattrs -cvf var_log.tar /var/log`.

Shrink the logical volume holding `/var/` by as much as you want for the space you need in `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit`. Then create two new logical volumes, one for `/var/log` and one for `/var/log/audit`. Format the new volumes.

Optionally remove the data from the existing `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit` directories. Mount the new volumes in `/var/log` and `/var/log/audit`. Unpack the TAR archives to restore the system logging and accounting data. Start system logging and accounting services.

Add these new volumes to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Will I need to list the new volumes in `/etc/fstab` in any particular order?

Comment: I suspect that order does matter, but I do not know the truth about it. Myself, I do certainly list them in the order that they should be mounted: for this, the first in the list is /var and then the others follow below /var

Comment: Ok this works nicely.  I added `/var/log/` and `/var/log/audit/` in sequence under `/var/` in fstab - no issues.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: link to [STIG](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx) has moved